# Thinkpad T430si Wireless Interface Soft-Blocks Intermitently

Tags: networking, 16.04, drivers, network-manager, intel-wireless

This is a follow-up to [Wireless Interface Hard Blocker, Cannot Bring Up](https://askubuntu.com/questions/891394/wireless-interface-hard-blocked-cannot-bring-up). Following the successful resolution of that issue, another problem began to happen - the wireless interface would intermitently become soft-block with no apparent reason. I have looked around, and it seems the commonly accepted solution is to blacklist a kernel module related to proprietary hardware.

For the time being, I have added the following script to my rc.local.

```bsh
rfkill event | grep --line-buffered "soft 1" | while read line ; do
    id=$(echo $line | grep -o "idx [[:digit:]]*" | grep -o "[[:digit:]]");
    rfkill unblock "$id"; 
done;
```

The said script programmatically unblock all interfaces that become blocked via a software block, thus providing a near seemless experience (besides the intermittent connects and disconnects from access points). I am not however satisfied with this solution as it is really bodged and hides the true problem.

Could you help me out? :)

Cheers!

**P.S.:** You can find all the necessary information about my computer wireless info [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/24241186/) (done using Ubuntu Forums' [wireless-info script](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=370108))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unreliable wireless connection with an Intel Centrino Advanced-N 6230](http://askubuntu.com/questions/663315/unreliable-wireless-connection-with-an-intel-centrino-advanced-n-6230)

Comment: Nice, thanks! Unfortunately I attempted it and I still have the problem

Comment: You might try disabling power saving on the wireless adapter as outlined [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/836271/ralink-pci-wifi-adaptor-intermittently-drops-connection)